# Why do I always get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix-multiplication, chain, mmc

This code is taken from a common algorithms book. The book uses an array starting from 1 instead of 0 for `m` but starts from 0 for `p`. How do I solve it ??

These are the errors:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
at MMC_Test.MemoizedMatrixChain(MMC_Test.java:8)
at MMC_Test.main(MMC_Test.java:36)
```

and code here

```java
public class MMC_Test {

public static int MemoizedMatrixChain(int[] p) {
    int n = p.length - 1;
    int[][] m = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j <= n; j++) {
            m[i][j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }
    return lookUpChain(m, p, 1, n);
}// MemoizedMatrixChain

public static int lookUpChain(int[][] m, int[] p, int i, int j) {
    if (m[i][j] > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        return m[i][j];
    }
    if (i == j) {
        m[i][j] = 0;
    } else {
        for (int k = i; k <= j - 1; k++) {
            int q = lookUpChain(m, p, i, k) 
                    + lookUpChain(m, p, k + 1, j)
                    + p[i - 1] * p[k] * p[j];
            if (q < m[i][j]) {
                m[i][j] = q;
            }
        }
    }
    return m[i][j];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] arr = { 30, 35, 15, 5, 10, 20, 25 };
    int result = MemoizedMatrixChain(arr);
    System.out.println(result);

}// main
```

}

Comment: Just replace `m[i]` (or similar) with `m[i-1]` everywhere.

Comment: I love this line `if (m[i][j] > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {`

Comment: @SJuan76 It's the place where indexes dance the bounds.

Comment: @RomanC can you tell me how any integer can be greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`? The condition is always false so it is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j <= n; j++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
```

and I haven't analyzed your code properly, but a guess is that

```
return lookUpChain(m, p, 1, n);
```

should be

```
return lookUpChain(m, p, 1, n - 1);
```

Comment: I had a typo on the last line. I'm not sure what the correct output for your program should be, but with the changes above it gives a result at least.

Comment: no i were changed it , but still have same errors

Comment: It runs on [ideone](http://ideone.com/BcxLA9).

Answer (score 0):

By creating this array:

```
 int[][] m = new int[n][n];
```

you have created a multidimensional array that ranges from:

```
m[0][0] => m[n-1][n-1]
```

There are still `n` spaces in the array, but we start from 0.

The problem with your code is you're using a `<=` operator in your for loops, when it should be a `<` operator.

Comment: i were try it , but still have same problem

Answer (score 0):

index should always be till n-1.

```
public static int MemoizedMatrixChain(int[] p) {
    int n = p.length - 1;
    int[][] m = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) { //change here
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) { //change here
            m[i][j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
    }
    return lookUpChain(m, p, 1, n);
}// MemoizedMatrixChain
```

Comment: still have same errors

Answer (score 0):

You have an array from 0 to (n - 1), but you use indices from 1 to n to access it.  You thus do not use the first element, but try to access a non-existing element after the last.

You can see the place where it happens first in the error message (line 8).  There may be further errors later in the code.

As a rule of thumb, always use indices from 0 to (n - 1), where n is the length of the array.  Then your loops start from i = 0 and run while i < n.  As soon as you start to add or subtract something from either bound, it should feel wrong (unless you do not want to access the whole array).

Comment: i know that, but how i can solve it ?